# Polymer custom element attributes as boolean typed values

Tags: polymer

While `Demo A` works, I would like to understand if it is possible to make it work like `Demo B`. Basically, to for the custom element to resolve `happyFlag` attribute as boolean type.

```
// Demo A - works. bob smiles. cat frowns.
<x-smiley name="Bob" happyFlag="true"></x-smiley>
<x-smiley name="Cat" happyFlag="false"></x-smiley>
<polymer-element name="x-smiley" attributes="name, happyFlag" noscript>
    <template>
        {{name}} is
        <span hidden?="{{happyFlag == 'true'}}">:-)</span>
        <span hidden?="{{happyFlag == 'false'}}">:-(</span>
        <hr>
    </template>
</polymer-element>

// Demo B - does not work (span always hidden)
<x-smiley name="Bob" happyFlag="true"></x-smiley>
<x-smiley name="Cat" happyFlag="false"></x-smiley>
<polymer-element name="x-smiley" attributes="name, happyFlag" noscript>
    <template>
        {{name}} is
        <span hidden?="{{happyFlag}}">:-)</span>
        <span hidden?="{{happyFlag}}">:-(</span>
        <hr>
    </template>
</polymer-element>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can give Polymer hints as to what type of input an attribute is. See the following example where I added the Polymer script and specifically the `this.happyFlag = false` in the created method. This line gives Polymer a hint that this value should be treated as a boolean. See [Polymer's Documentation](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#propertiesmethods) about hinting types.

```
<polymer-element name="x-smiley" attributes="name, happyFlag">
<template>
    {{name}} is {{happyFlag}}
    <span hidden?="{{happyFlag}}">:-)</span>
    <span hidden?="{{happyFlag}}">:-(</span>
    <hr>
</template>
<script>
  Polymer('x-smiley', {
    created: function() {
        this.happyFlag = false;
    },
    ready: function() {
    }
  })
</script>
```

Comment: Fwiw, you don't have to set the property in `created` you could simply put it on the prototype.

Comment: This is true. I had that in the answer originally but changed it after reading the warning about using the prototype in the docs. They only seem to be warning against setting up objects or arrays in the prototype so I guess it's safe either way for this particular example.

Comment: Also you can use `publish:{ happyFlag:true }` to set its type.